# $A$-points of a fiber of a morphism of schemes over $k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of schemes over a field $k$.  For any point $y\in Y$, we have the fiber of $f$ over $y$ defined as the fiber product $X_y=X\times_Y\mathrm{Spec }\;k(y)$, where $k(y)\cong \mathcal{O}_y/\mathfrak{m}_y$ is the residue field of $y$.

If $A$ is a commutative $k(y)$-algebra, I'd like to describe the $A$-points of $X_y$, which means I'm interested in maps of schemes $\mathrm{Spec}\;A\to X_y$.  Using the universal property of the fiber product, is this equivalent to the $A$-points of $X$ where $A$ is a commutative $k$-algebra via $k\hookrightarrow k(y)$?

My intuition for algebraic geometry is horrible.  I'd certainly appreciate any illuminating description of how to view the $A$-points of the fiber $X_y$.  Thank you.

Comment: They are essentially the $A$-points of $X$ that lie over $y$ – but the latter condition is still something that needs to be imposed separately.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Thank you for the comment, although I don't understand what you are saying.  Can you be more clear about what you mean by the "$A$-points of $X$ that lie over $y$?"  It seems you have some way of thinking about this intuitively, but I'm in the dark over here!

Comment: Do you understand fibre products in, say, $\mathbf{Top}$ or any other conventional setting?

Comment: @ZhenLin: Yes.  I probably best understand them in $\mathbf{Top}$, and I understand that the universal property is the same for $\mathbf{Sch}$, so there should be some way to allow my intuition in topology guide me here, but with schemes there is no easy way to even write down what the fiber product is as a set.  At least, I'm unaware of any.  I always just rely on the universal property if I ever want to do anything with a fiber product of schemes.

Comment: You could also work with the algebras and take the tensor products. The nice thing is that in your case the underlying topological space of a fiber over a point actually is the fiber in the topological sense. To see this try to write down what $X_y$ looks like when $X$ is affine by using the fact that it is $\operatorname{Spec}$ of a certain tensor product and chase around where the prime ideals go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$I just want to expand on Pece's answer a bit to try to make it more explicit. Consider some affine open subset $U = \operatorname{Spec} B \subseteq X$ intersecting the fiber $X_y$ nontrivially and some affine open $V = \operatorname{Spec} R \subseteq Y$ containing $y$. By possibly shrinking $\operatorname{Spec} B$ we can assume that the morphism $f$ sends $U$ to $V$. Finally, suppose that $y$ corresponds to the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$.

Then the inclusion $y \hookrightarrow Y$ corresponds to the composition $R \to R_{\mathfrak{p}} \to R_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}R_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Similarly, the morphism $f: U \to V$ corresponds to a ring homomorphism $R \to B$ making $B$ an $R$ algebra. Then the fiber product $U_y$ corresponds to the tensor product of rings, i.e., the pushout diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
B_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}B_{\mathfrak{p}} @<<<  R_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}; \\
@AAA @AAA \\
B @<<< R
\end{CD}
$$

The nice thing here is that we can usually compute this ring to get an explicit handle of the fiber. Then an $A$-valued point of the fiber $U_y$ is explicitly a ring homomorphism $B \to A$ that factors as $B \to B_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}B_{\mathfrak{p}} \to A$ and is compatible with the diagram above. Stated differently, it is just an $R$-algebra morphism $B_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}B_{\mathfrak{p}} \to A$.

For the general case, we just find affine $U_i = \operatorname{Spec} B_i$ in $X$ whose union contains $X_y$ and whose image under $f$ is contained in $\operatorname{Spec} R$. The above argument goes through for each $U_i$ so that

$$
(U_i)_y = \operatorname{Spec} {B_i}_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}{B_i}_{\mathfrak{p}} \enspace \enspace \text{and} \enspace \enspace X_y = \bigcup_i (U_i)_y. 
$$

Then an $A$ valued point of $X_y$ is just a map of schemes $g: \spec A \to X$ such that $g^{-1}(U_i)$ cover $\spec A$ and for each affine $\spec A' \subset g^{-1}(U_i)$, the induced ring homomorphism $B_i \to A'$ lifts to an $R-$algebra homomorphism ${B_i}_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}{B_i}_{\mathfrak{p}} \to A'$.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\spec}[1]{\mathrm{Spec}\,(#1)}$
I'm new at this, so it is more thoughts put into words than an answer.

[image]

By definition of a fiber product (in any locally small category for that matter), we have :
$$ X_y(-) = X(-) \times_{Y(-)} \spec{k(y)}(-)$$
(where $Z(-)$ is the functor of points $\hom_{k-\mathbf{Sch}}(-,Z)$ of the $k$-scheme $Z$).

Explicitely, for a $k$-scheme $Z$, $X_y(Z) = \{ (\varphi,\psi) \in X(Z) \times \spec{k(y)}(Z) : f \circ \varphi = i_y \circ \psi \}$ where $i_y$ is the (inclusion) morphism $\spec{k(y)} \to Y$. But then, the functor of points of $\spec{k(y)}$ admits a nice description : any morphism $Z \to \spec {k(y)}$ is topologically the constant map to the single point of $\spec {k(y)}$, and the map of structuring sheaves is just a morphism $k(y) \to \mathcal O_Z(Z)$ of $k$-algebra.

Now take $Z$ to be $\spec A$ for a $k$-algebra $A$, we have :
$$ \spec{k(y)} (A) \cong \hom_{k}(k(y), A). $$
So an element of $X_y(A)$ is the data of a morphism $\spec A \to X$ and a structure of $k(y)$-algebra on $A$ extending the structure of $k$-algebra, such that

- topologically, $\spec A$ factors through $f^{-1}(\{y\})$,
- for every $x \in f^{-1}(\{y\})$, the structure of $k(y)$-algebra of $A$ factors through the residue field $k(x)$ of $x$.

If now $A$ is a $k(y)$-algebra and you're interesting in the $A$-points of $X_y$ **as $k(y)$-schemes$^{(1)}$**, then the structure of $k(y)$-algebra is imposed but the conditions remain. So I would say that your assumption

> Using the universal property of the fiber product, is this equivalent to the $A$-points of $X$ where $A$ is a commutative $k$-algebra via $k \hookrightarrow k(y)$?

was not restrictive enough.

---

(1) This is not clear in the OP what kind of $A$-points you are looking for.